# Display php code with fwrite inside a php file

Tags: php, fwrite

Hello i am using the code bellow to write the following line inside a .php file.

```
$stringDatar = "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC '-//W3C//DTD XHTML+RDFa 1.0//EN'\n";
fwrite($handler, $stringDatar);
```

I am trying to do the same to write inside a php file with the following code but it doesn't wite the php code.

```
$stringDatar = "'.<?php $_GET['p']\n.'";
fwrite($handler, $stringDatar);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What must be in file? Can you provide example of output?

Comment: how are you calling `fopen`, is `$handler` a resource, or does the `fopen` call fail? What mode is the handle in (`a`, `w`, ...?) any specific errors/warnings (turn display_errors on, and set the error_reporting to the maximum setting (`E_STRICT|E_ALL`). You're also doing weird things with the dots (concat operator). To concatenate string, the `.` shouldn't be inside the quotes: `$foo = 'a string'; $foo = '.rest';` reassings `$foo`, to concatenate: `$foo .= 'rest';` (note `.=`) or `$foo = $foo . 'rest';` It's [basic syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables are expanded inside double quotes, so it's putting the value of `$_GET['p']` into the file. You need to escape the dollar sign so it will be written literally.

```
$stringDatar = "'.<?php \$_GET['p']\n.'";
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this format which might be more more comfortable

```
<?php

$content = <<< END
<?php
  \$d = 5;
  echo "\$d".PHP_EOL;
  echo \$_GET['arg'];

END;
file_put_contents("filename.php", $content);
```

fileContents:

```
<?php
  $d = 5;
  echo "$d".PHP_EOL;
  echo $_GET['arg'];
```

Comment: Personally, I'd also advise against using `"\n"` in favor of the predefined `PHP_EOL` constant

Comment: ok, but it's just an example, you can also say that $d is not a good variable name, doesn't matter for the example (:

Comment: Sure, just added the comment for completeness -> the OP is clearly in the early stages of learning, so I figured it's best to expose them to code that shows _"best practices"_ as much as possible... there's a ton of crap-code out there already (not saying your answer is crap, just saying that many tutorials contain bad code examples)